# Heroku Flask API - How to improve response time when serving large JSON and image files?

Tags: python, api, heroku, redis, heroku-postgres

I have a Python Flask API using gunicorn hosted on a Basic tier Heroku server. The API queries a Basic Heroku Postgres database for each endpoint of the API to retrieve and return the data. Since this tier of the database allows 20 connections, I have set the Python file to 17 workers, to handle concurrent requests faster.

The problem is, when serving large JSON files where I have to query the database first and then return a jsonify version of it, or query a table with images and return that, the response times range from 3 to 6 seconds or so, which is really not desirable. Especially if many users are using the API at once, it may become even slower.

How can I speed up serving large JSON files or images of like 2MB each, when I am using a Postgres database for the API?

Is there a way to cache them, would that speed things up? I have heard about Heroku Redis, would that improve the response times exponentially? How do commerical APIs do it, and how can I replicate it on Heroku with my Flask API?

Comment: There are really several questions in one here, so it's not an appropriate question format for StackOverflow, but there are several things you can work on. Image optimization, a caching CDN, splitting your JSON into smaller files or streaming it (depending on how it's being consumed), gzipping your responses if you're not doing that already, and increasing your resources (like your database and server memory and CPU, and max connections, depending on what your metrics are telling you), are all worth checking out.

Comment: And if you're storing images in Postgres, moving those to object storage (like S3) would definitely help.